# Вставить в ASP.NET страницу заранее сгенерированное содержимое

Tags: c#, asp.net

Господа. Я совсем не знаю ASP.NET, но имею представление о HTML и нормально пишу на C#.

Я хотел сделать так: в файле `Default.aspx.cs` в методе `Page_Load()` я получаю сложную страницу, которую я сделал в своём собственном C#-методе, со всеми div'ами, style'ами и прочим контентом.
Потом в том месте в фале `Default.aspx` я просто нахожу тег `<body> </body>`, и в это место вставляю свою строчку - как то так: `<body> <%=myString%> </body>`

Во всяком случае, во времена обычного ASP, без всякого .NET, это нормально работало. Но сейчас что то не работает.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ура! Заработало!
Я прочитал сообщение об ошибке: "Compiler Error Message: CS0122: 'Default.myString' is inaccessible due to its protection level".
Сделал строку public - и всё вставилось!